# Comparing powershell output

Tags: powershell, office365

We use helpedesk software on our company, and it is set up to pull email from an IMAP enabled mailbox.  Occasionally, the helpdesk program will act up, and stop pulling messages. The service and other indicators show that everything is working fine, but messages will start queueing in our helpdesk mailbox.

So, we would like to monitor the item count in the mailbox to see if it gets backed up, and if so send an automated email.

I can query the  mailbox store on Office365 by using this command.  It returns the number of hidden items.. in this case 46.

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity support@mydomain.com -FolderScope Inbox | ?{$_.FolderPath -like '/Inbox'} | Select Name, ItemsInFolder

Name  ItemsInFolder
----  -------------
Inbox            46
```

I don't understand how to compare the output to see if it passes some threshold value, such as 50.   Once it passes the threshold, I can take action such as send an email, or restart the problem service, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# store what you need in a variable
# -ExpandProperty ensures you only get the value without the property name
$count = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity support@mydomain.com -FolderScope Inbox |
    Where-Object { $_.FolderPath -like "/Inbox" } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty ItemsInFolder

# compare and alert
if($count -ge 50) {
    "50 or more mails in Inbox, send alert mail"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do here is pretty simple.  first store the result of the cmdlet you have already written in a variable, such as `$items`

```
$items = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics ...
```

Then compare the value of `$items.itemsinfolder` to your threshold

```
if($items.itemsinfolder -gt 50){
  send your email, you can access the $items.name property and include it in the body if that is helpful
}
```